# Select conversationId from invited

Tags: php, mysql

I have a conversation table and one invited table. The conversation table stores all the message along with conversationId(No need to know more than that). The invited table have two columns called conversationId and profileId. I want to select the conversationId that match a list of invited. How do I do that in MYSQL and PHP?

So far I've done this in PHP:

```
 $sql = "
    SELECT invited.conversationId, count(invited.conversationId) AS cof
    FROM conversation_invited AS invited 
    WHERE   invited.profileId = '$profileId'//This is myself
    ";
    $i = 0;
    foreach($invited as $v){//$invited is an array of invited's profileIds
            $sql .= "
    AND     invited.profileId = '$v' ";
        $i++;
    }

    $sql .= "
    GROUP BY invited.conversationId
    ORDER BY count(invited.conversationId) ASC
    LIMIT 1
";
```

The sql statement that I want to create wants to match the invited exactly. If for instance the invited array consist of ['27', '34', '36'], than I want to find the conversation(Id) that match the invited array exactly. Nor less nor more invited

Comment: For god's sake, escape those variables you use in your SQL query! http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$invites = join(',', array_merge($invited, (array)$profileId))
$sql = "
    SELECT invited.conversationId, count(invited.conversationId) AS cof
    FROM conversation_invited AS invited 
    WHERE invited.profileId IN($invites)
    GROUP BY invited.conversationId
    ORDER BY count(invited.conversationId) ASC
    LIMIT 1
";
```

Comment: Hi there is one problem with this solution. "I myself" is invited to many conversations. And if a conversation has three invited, the sql statement above will never select that conversationId, beacause Iäm invited to conversations with only two invited. So "select the conversationId that match a list of invited" will not be appropiate to use the above sql statement

Comment: Let say that I'm invited to two conversation, one with three invited and one with two, both including myself as invited. The sql statement that I want to create wants to match the invited. If for instance the invited array consist of ['27', '34', '36'], than I want to find the conversation(Id) that match the invited array exactly. With the above statement, it will only return the conversation with two invited

Comment: Maybe you must use `OR` instead of `AND` ?

Comment: Yeah, but `OR` will behave the same as `IN` wouldn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_quotes(&$item) {
    $item = "'$item'";
} 
array_walk($invited, 'add_quotes'); 
$t = implode(',', $invited);
$sql = "
    SELECT invited.conversationId, count(invited.conversationId) AS cof
    FROM conversation_invited AS invited 
    WHERE invited.profileId IN ('$profileId', $t)
    GROUP BY invited.conversationId
    ORDER BY count(invited.conversationId) ASC
    LIMIT 1
";
```

Note that the above will change the values in `$invited`.